# Error in installing libraries permanently in COLAB

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I wrote a below code to permanently install the smplx library in COLAB

```
nb_path = '/content/drive/My\ Drive/project'
!pip install --target=$nb_path --upgrade smplx
```

Next Day I tried running my project and it is not able to import the library

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "smplifyx/main.py", line 31, in <module>
  import smplx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smplx'
```